# Spim Crashing to Mips Reading from File

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I am trying to read a file using mips assembly but every time I run the code, Spim crashes.
I got the code from several websites which all had the same code and it worked fine for them.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
        .data
str:        .asciiz "Welcome :\n"
fin:        .asciiz "test.txt"
buffer:     .space 1024

    .text
    .globl main
main:
        la $a0,str
        li $v0,4
        syscall
#open file
    li $v0, 13               #open a file
    la $a0, fin          # load file name
    li $a1, 0                # Open for reading
    li $a2, 0
    syscall
    move $s6, $v0           # load file descriptor

    li $v0, 14               #read from file
    add $a0, $s6, $0           #file descriptor
    la $a1, buffer          # address of buffer to which to read
    li $a2, 1024            # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall  

    li   $v0, 16         # system call for close file
    add $a0, $s6, $0        # file descriptor to close
    syscall

Exit:
        li $v0,10
        syscall
```

Comment: You should have stated how spim crashes (including any error messages), also its version. That said, the code is broken, for the read you obviously need to pass the file descriptor to read from (copy `$v0` into `$a0`). This shouldn't make spim crash, and it doesn't crash mine (which is version `8.0`).

Comment: I deeply apologize but I have passed the descriptor but I forgot to write it here !!!
I am using QtSpim (version 9.1.12) and once I run the code it says qtspim has stopped working and that windows is checking for a solution and then spim closes!